# PHP MySQL TIMESTAMPDIFF with seconds not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have been testing this for hours and can not seem to get it to work. Below is a simplified version of what I'm working with. Each time I test it I get 0 results.  I have many entries in the database that are before and after :start.

```
$bind = array(':start'=>'01-31-2015 10:00 AM' );
$select  = "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,dateTime,:start)>0";
$results = $db->select("schedule", $select, $bind);
```

I suppose I should give the plain version which is as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,dateTime,'01-31-2015 10:00 AM')>0
```

In the select above dateTime would be in the same format as :start.

I don't know if I have to use a specific date format but I would like to use the existing format if possible.

Comment: They are in the same format they are not the same. dateTime would be another set say '01-31-2015 12:00 PM' for example

Comment: As I said above I have times < and > in the database but it comes up with 0 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `TIMESTAMP()` around your date string as sometimes MySQL doesn't interpret it as a date until you do, and you get weird results. Also the date format for MySQL is

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,dateTime,TIMESTAMP('2015-01-31 10:00:00'))>0
```

Comment: Im assuming I will have to do this with both items including dateTime?

Comment: @DouglasCottrell, if dateTime is a field of type DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, then no.

Comment: I am thinking it may be my date format that is breaking the system

Comment: @DouglasCottrell, Yes, you need it to be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.  Not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE  `dateTime` < '2015-01-31 10:00:00'
```